# Is development mode of Open Liberty executed in foreground or background

Tags: java, open-liberty

In Open Liberty server there are several goals to start it like `liberty:run`, `liberty:start` and `liberty:dev`.

In the docs I see that `run` executes the server in foreground and `start` in background but I can't find if the development mode `dev` executes it in foreground or background.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to see the `dev` mode in action, have a look at the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZVVTO5m4ss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dev mode runs in the foreground just like `liberty:run`.  The main difference / advantage between the two is the hot reload feature which will pick up source changes in your app and reload the server and tests.  More information about dev mode can be found here: https://openliberty.io/blog/2019/10/22/liberty-dev-mode.html

Comment: I think so. I found that in `dev` mode the server keep responding to key events in the console and this is a strong clue that it runs in foreground. But I would like an official documentation statement about it.